# Enable Mesh Symmetry not working

Tags: transforms, mirror, mirror-modifier

I am modeling a frame and I want the both extrudes to mirror eachother (Move them to the outside) I have the mesh symmetry enabled and the Origin is in the middle of the object but its not working

[image]

Comment: can u provide blend file? normally this should work, if the origin of the object is in the middle of the faces.

Comment: Are your vertices perfectly symmetrical? The X, Y or Z mirror editing only works when there is a **perfect** symmetrical correspondance for the vertex you are editing. If there is the slightest difference, it won't work. You can read more about it here https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/modeling/meshes/editing/mesh_options.html#x-mirror